# Ubuntu python 3.7 to 3.8 update alternatives

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.8

I am attempting to upgrade python3.7 to 3.8 on ubuntu.
After using

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

python -V and python3 -V both point to Python 3.7.0.
This should have been because I haven't updated the alternatives, but running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

says that I have no alternatives to configure.
I look into the file system and can only find files labelled 3.8, none labelled 3.7, yet python -V says the current version is 3.7.0.

I followed a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261775/why-i-cant-install-python-3-8) to install 3.8 from the zip file, and now, python3.8 -V says I have a version 3.8.3. Indeed, I now have files labelled 3.8 and 3.8.3 in the file system. However, update-alternatives still says there are no alternatives.
I run the following two config commands anyway, of which the first gives no error, the second says there are no alternatives.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.8
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.8
```

python --version still says it is running 3.7.0

I have read that it isn't a good course of action to attempt to remove python entirely and start from scratch and I am aware that I have probably done things I shouldn't have to get into this mess, but is there anything I can do to fix it without wiping the laptop??

Comment: Do `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and see what it points to.  Also do `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: Both commands give 'cannot access '/usr/bin/python3': No such file or directory'...

Comment: That's surprising.  That's normally where Python is installed, unless you did a private install (as non-root).  Try this:  `which python` and `which python3` to see where it's finding them.

Comment: Neither of those commands show anything but `which python3.8` points to `/usr/local/bin/python3.8`. There is a file at `/usr/bin/python3` but `which python3` isn't pointing to it. I could create an alias to point to it though? As far as I know I only did root installations.

Comment: It sounds like your installs may have been made to inconsistent areas.  If you run `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 --version`, it should show 3.8, so you could run that directly, or change your python3 link to point there, and add a python link to point to your python3 link.

Comment: Yes, running that gives me 3.8.3. I will just link python and python3 to the 3.8 directory then. Thank you for your help! I just hope this won't cause other future problems..

Comment: Adding the symbolic links is pretty safe.  Usually the python3 link will point to the specific release (3.7, 3.8, etc.), and the python link will point to either the python2 or the python3 link.  That way, to switch from 3.7 to 3.8, you only need to change the python3 link.

Answer (score 0):

After pointing python and python3 to python 3.8.3, other python installations like jupyter and anaconda have been running smoothly with no problems.